# How can I check If I got null from json?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, nsmutablearray

Here I got from JSON

[{"photo":null}]

and I use this code

```
NSMutableArray *jPhoto = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[jsonDict valueForKey:@"photo"]];
```

How can I check it if I want to use if() ??

edit

here is JSON Data

```
   [{"photo":
              [{"image":"http:\/\/www.yohyeh.com\/upload\/shisetsu\/13157\/photo\/1304928459.jpg","title":"test picture","content":"this is description for test picture.\r\n\u8aac\u660e\u6587\u306a\u306e\u306b\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb\u30fb"}
              ,{"image":"http:\/\/www.yohyeh.com\/upload\/shisetsu\/13157\/photo\/1304928115.jpg","title":"nothing","content":"iMirai"}
              ,{"image":"http:\/\/www.yohyeh.com\/upload\/shisetsu\/13157\/photo\/1303276769.jpg","title":"iMirai","content":"Staff"}]}
  ]
```

and here is my JSON parser

```
NSError *theError = nil;     
    NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yohyeh.com/apps/get_sub_detail.php?id=%@&menu=photo",g_id];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[[NSURLResponse alloc]init] autorelease];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];   
    NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [string JSONValue];
```

Thank for help

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: I use JSON-framework.And there are a lot attribute in photo,not just image link but many thing.I'm not sure that I'm correct.But I think NSMutable is okay. or not ??? please giude me. : )

Comment: It’d help if you posted a more complete example of the JSON data as well as the code you’re using to parse them.

Comment: oh by this.If I use NSMutableArray.I can use this 


    if([jPhoto objectAtIndex:0]== [NSNull null])
    { 
    }

and It work. thank for many help. But I'm still waiting for Bavarious's guide. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe most JSON parsers represent `null` as `[NSNull null]`.

Considering `jsonDict` points to that single element in the array, then the following should work:

```
if ([jsonDict objectForKey:@"photo"] == [NSNull null]) {
    // it's null
}
```

---

**Edit based on comment:** so `jsonDict`, despite its name, is an array. In that case, rename `jsonDict` to `jsonArray` to avoid further confusion. Then, considering `jsonArray` points to an array similar to the example posted in the question:

```
NSArray *photos = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"photo"];
for (id photo in photos) {
    if (photo == [NSNull null]) {
        // photo is null
    }
    else {
        // photo isn't null
    }
}
```

---

**Further edit based on OP’s modified question:**

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [string JSONValue];

NSArray *photos = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"photo"];
for (id photo in photos) {
    if (photo == [NSNull null]) {
        // photo is null
    }
    else {
        // photo isn't null. It's an array
        NSArray *innerPhotos = photo;
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh it crash.Here is an error 

-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x58938e0
2011-05-19 11:10:47.131 iLife[2012:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x58938e0'

Comment: This means that `jsonDict` is an array, not a dictionary. Please see my last comment on your question.

Answer (score 7):

Macros can be helpful if payload is complex JSON structure having possible  values.

```
#define SET_IF_NOT_NULL(TARGET, VAL) if(VAL != [NSNull null]) { TARGET = VAL; }
```

and macro can be referenced like

```
SET_IF_NOT_NULL(myRecord.name, [jsonData objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

Comment: May i know what you mean by myrecord.name

Comment: Very good solution, instead of creating categories for NSObject and excessive 'if' conditions. Vote up, @Ramesh

Comment: Voted Up! I'm having error while trying to use this macro for parsing double values. `Invalid operands to binary expression ('double _Nullable' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull')` and `Invalid operands to binary expression ('double _Nullable' and 'void *')` How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

There's no easy way of dealing with this, but the way I do it is to make a category on NSObject:

```
@interface NSObject (NotNull)

- (instancetype)notNull;

@end
```

Implemented like so:

```
@implementation NSObject (NotNull)

- (instancetype)notNull
{
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation NSNull (NotNull)

- (instancetype)notNull
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Then you can send `notNull` to any optional object in a JSON dict and you'll get `nil`
back if it's NSNull. Otherwise you get the original object. For example:

```
self.parentIdentifier = [dictionary[@"parent_id"] notNull];
```

Comment: Love it! I have just added a three letter prefix to the method name just to be extra safe :)

Comment: @joerick The solution is working but I didn't get the logic behind this. If possible can please explain its workflow that will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to check for `[jPhoto count]` or `[NSNull null]`

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this helps.

-(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonCheckforNull:(NSMutableDictionary *)json{

NSMutableDictionary* strongjson=[json mutableCopy];

```
for (NSString *ktr in json) {

    NSObject *str=[json objectForKey:ktr];

    if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        if (!(str==[NSNull null])) {
            NSArray *temp = [json allKeysForObject:str];
            str=[[self ArrayCheckforNull:(NSMutableArray*)str]mutableCopy];
            NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
            [strongjson removeObjectForKey:key];
            [strongjson setObject:str forKey:key];
        }
        else
        {
            NSArray *temp = [strongjson allKeysForObject:str];
            NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
            [strongjson removeObjectForKey:key];
            [strongjson setObject:@"-----" forKey:key];
        }

    }
    else if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        if (!(str==[NSNull null])) {
            str=[[self jsonCheckforNull:str]mutableCopy];
            NSArray *temp = [strongjson allKeysForObject:str];
            NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
            [strongjson removeObjectForKey:key];
            [strongjson setObject:str forKey:key];
        }
        else
        {
            NSArray *temp = [strongjson allKeysForObject:str];
            NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
            [strongjson removeObjectForKey:key];
            [strongjson setObject:@"-----" forKey:key];
        }

    }

    else {

        if (str ==[NSNull null]) {
            NSArray *temp = [strongjson allKeysForObject:str];
            NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
            [strongjson removeObjectForKey:key];
            [strongjson setObject:@"----" forKey:key];
        }

    }

}
return strongjson;
```

}

-(NSMutableArray *)ArrayCheckforNull:(NSMutableArray *)arr{

```
NSObject *str;
NSMutableArray* strongArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arr]mutableCopy];
for (str in arr)
{

    if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        if (!(str==[NSNull null])) {
            str=[[self ArrayCheckforNull:(NSMutableArray *)str]mutableCopy];
            [strongArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [strongArray addObject:str];
        }
        else
        {
            [strongArray removeObject:str];
            [strongArray addObject:@"----"];

        }

    }
    else if ([str isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        if (!(str==[NSNull null])) {
            str=[[self jsonCheckforNull:(NSMutableDictionary*)str]mutableCopy];
            [strongArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [strongArray addObject:str];

        }
        else
        {
            [strongArray removeObject:str];
            [strongArray addObject:@"----"];
        }

    }

    else {

        if (str ==[NSNull null]) {
            [strongArray removeObject:str];
            [strongArray addObject:@"----"];
        }


    }

}
return strongArray;
```

}