# Get values from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Hi I'm new to iOS development. I want to get response and add those values to variable.

I tried it but I'm getting below response. I don't understand why there is slashes in this response.

```
@"[{\"VisitorID\":\"2864983a-e26b-441a-aedf-84e2a1770b8e\",\"ProfileID\":\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\",\"CompanyID\":null,\"VisitorName\":\"kanasalingam\",\"OperatorName\":\"baman\",\"Image\":null,\"isocode\":\"lk\",\"CurrentOperator\":[\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\"]},{\"VisitorID\":\"133bc108-b3bf-468a-9397-e1b0dba449db\",\"ProfileID\":\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\",\"CompanyID\":null,\"VisitorName\":\"kumar\",\"OperatorName\":\"baman\",\"Image\":null,\"isocode\":\"lk\",\"CurrentOperator\":[\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\"]}]"
```

I tried this :

```
- (void) sendOtherActiveChats:(NSDictionary *) chatDetails{
    NSLog(@"inside sendOtherActiveChats");
    NSLog(@"otherDetails  Dictionary : %@ ", chatDetails);

    NSString *VisitorID = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"VisitorID"];
    NSString *ProfileID = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"ProfileID"];
    NSString *CompanyID = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"CompanyID"];
    NSString *VisitorName = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"VisitorName"];
    NSString *OperatorName = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"OperatorName"];
    NSString *isocode = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"isocode"];

    NSLog(@"------------------------Other Active Chats -----------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"VisitorID      : %@" , VisitorID);
    NSLog(@"ProfileID      : %@" , ProfileID);
    NSLog(@"CompanyID      : %@" , CompanyID);
    NSLog(@"VisitorName    : %@" , VisitorName);
    NSLog(@"OperatorName   : %@" , OperatorName);
    NSLog(@"countryCode: %@" , isocode);
    NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

}
```

Can some one help me to get the values out of this string ?

Comment: There are slashes because of the `"`, and your object seems more to be a NSString of JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting Array of Dictionary in response, but your response is in string so you convert it to `NSArray` using `NSJSONSerialization` like this way for that convert your response string to `NSData` and after that use that data with `JSONObjectWithData:` to get array from it.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"VisitorID\":\"2864983a-e26b-441a-aedf-84e2a1770b8e\",\"ProfileID\":\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\",\"CompanyID\":null,\"VisitorName\":\"kanasalingam\",\"OperatorName\":\"baman\",\"Image\":null,\"isocode\":\"lk\",\"CurrentOperator\":[\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\"]},{\"VisitorID\":\"133bc108-b3bf-468a-9397-e1b0dba449db\",\"ProfileID\":\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\",\"CompanyID\":null,\"VisitorName\":\"kumar\",\"OperatorName\":\"baman\",\"Image\":null,\"isocode\":\"lk\",\"CurrentOperator\":[\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\"]}]";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *e;
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
```

Now loop through the array and access the each dictionary from it.

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
     NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"VisitorID"]);
     ... and so on.
}
```

Comment: That Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So you have `JSON` string and `array` of 2 objects. So write following code

This will convert `JSON` string to `Array`

```
NSData *myJSONData = [YOUR_JSON_STRING dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *arrayResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myJSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Now use for loop and print data as

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayResponse.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dictionaryTemp = [arrayResponse objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"VisitorID : %@",[dictionaryTemp valueForKey:@"VisitorID"]);
    NSLog(@"ProfileID : %@",[dictionaryTemp valueForKey:@"ProfileID"]);
    NSLog(@"CompanyID : %@",[dictionaryTemp valueForKey:@"CompanyID"]);
    NSLog(@"VisitorName : %@",[dictionaryTemp valueForKey:@"VisitorName"]);
}
```

Now there are good chances that you will get NULL for some keys and it can cause in crash. So avoid those crash by using [Null validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440004/modify-getters-to-avoid-nsnull/41440208#41440208).

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey` unless you know exactly what KVC is and why this method is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse your string.

```
NSString *aString = @"[{\"VisitorID\":\"2864983a-e26b-441a-aedf-84e2a1770b8e\",\"ProfileID\":\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\",\"CompanyID\":null,\"VisitorName\":\"kanasalingam\",\"OperatorName\":\"baman\",\"Image\":null,\"isocode\":\"lk\",\"CurrentOperator\":[\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\"]},{\"VisitorID\":\"133bc108-b3bf-468a-9397-e1b0dba449db\",\"ProfileID\":\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\",\"CompanyID\":null,\"VisitorName\":\"kumar\",\"OperatorName\":\"baman\",\"Image\":null,\"isocode\":\"lk\",\"CurrentOperator\":[\"69c02265-abca-4716-8a2f-ac5d642f876a\"]}]";

NSData *data = [aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"VisitorID"]);
```