# get values out of jSON Array - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new to objective-c and iOS development. I need to get json values from a url and get values out of it.

**This is the json value I am getting.**

```
 "\"[{\\\"VisitorId\\\":\\\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\\\",\\\"OperatorID\\\":null,\\\"VisitorSignalId\\\":\\\"06c6b36f-0d05-4f0c-bdee-1744c2cb6519\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"Visitor\\\",\\\"Messagetext\\\":\\\"baman123 has joined the chat!\\\",\\\"IsJoin\\\":true,\\\"MessageTime\\\":\\\"2017-01-09 06:25:47\\\",\\\"File\\\":null,\\\"MessageType\\\":\\\"JoinMessage\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"baman123\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"baman123@gmail.com\\\",\\\"IP\\\":\\\"123.231.122.233\\\",\\\"Page\\\":\\\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\\\",\\\"Rating\\\":\\\"No Rating\\\",\\\"Image\\\":null,\\\"CurrentOpImage\\\":null,\\\"FileUploadDetails\\\":null,\\\"FirstOperatorName\\\":null,\\\"OperatorCount\\\":1,\\\"RequestTranscript\\\":false,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"OS\\\":null,\\\"Broswer\\\":null,\\\"Mobile\\\":null,\\\"iso_code\\\":null},{\\\"VisitorId\\\":\\\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\\\",\\\"OperatorID\\\":null,\\\"VisitorSignalId\\\":null,\\\"Type\\\":\\\"Visitor\\\",\\\"Messagetext\\\":\\\"hi this is baman\\\",\\\"IsJoin\\\":false,\\\"MessageTime\\\":\\\"2017-01-09 08:01:07\\\",\\\"File\\\":null,\\\"MessageType\\\":\\\"NormalMessage\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"baman123\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"baman123@gmail.com\\\",\\\"IP\\\":\\\"123.231.122.233\\\",\\\"Page\\\":\\\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\\\",\\\"Rating\\\":\\\"No Rating\\\",\\\"Image\\\":null,\\\"CurrentOpImage\\\":null,\\\"FileUploadDetails\\\":null,\\\"FirstOperatorName\\\":null,\\\"OperatorCount\\\":1,\\\"RequestTranscript\\\":false,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"OS\\\":null,\\\"Broswer\\\":null,\\\"Mobile\\\":null,\\\"iso_code\\\":null},{\\\"VisitorId\\\":\\\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\\\",\\\"OperatorID\\\":null,\\\"VisitorSignalId\\\":null,\\\"Type\\\":\\\"Visitor\\\",\\\"Messagetext\\\":\\\"are you there\\\",\\\"IsJoin\\\":false,\\\"MessageTime\\\":\\\"2017-01-09 08:01:10\\\",\\\"File\\\":null,\\\"MessageType\\\":\\\"NormalMessage\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"baman123\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"baman123@gmail.com\\\",\\\"IP\\\":\\\"123.231.122.233\\\",\\\"Page\\\":\\\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\\\",\\\"Rating\\\":\\\"No Rating\\\",\\\"Image\\\":null,\\\"CurrentOpImage\\\":null,\\\"FileUploadDetails\\\":null,\\\"FirstOperatorName\\\":null,\\\"OperatorCount\\\":1,\\\"RequestTranscript\\\":false,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"OS\\\":null,\\\"Broswer\\\":null,\\\"Mobile\\\":null,\\\"iso_code\\\":null},{\\\"VisitorId\\\":\\\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\\\",\\\"OperatorID\\\":null,\\\"VisitorSignalId\\\":null,\\\"Type\\\":\\\"Visitor\\\",\\\"Messagetext\\\":\\\"fuck u\\\",\\\"IsJoin\\\":false,\\\"MessageTime\\\":\\\"2017-01-09 08:01:14\\\",\\\"File\\\":null,\\\"MessageType\\\":\\\"NormalMessage\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"baman123\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"baman123@gmail.com\\\",\\\"IP\\\":\\\"123.231.122.233\\\",\\\"Page\\\":\\\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\\\",\\\"Rating\\\":\\\"No Rating\\\",\\\"Image\\\":null,\\\"CurrentOpImage\\\":null,\\\"FileUploadDetails\\\":null,\\\"FirstOperatorName\\\":null,\\\"OperatorCount\\\":1,\\\"RequestTranscript\\\":false,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"OS\\\":null,\\\"Broswer\\\":null,\\\"Mobile\\\":null,\\\"iso_code\\\":null},{\\\"VisitorId\\\":\\\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\\\",\\\"OperatorID\\\":null,\\\"VisitorSignalId\\\":null,\\\"Type\\\":\\\"Visitor\\\",\\\"Messagetext\\\":\\\"sathyabaman\\\",\\\"IsJoin\\\":false,\\\"MessageTime\\\":\\\"2017-01-09 08:37:15\\\",\\\"File\\\":null,\\\"MessageType\\\":\\\"NormalMessage\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"baman123\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"baman123@gmail.com\\\",\\\"IP\\\":\\\"123.231.122.233\\\",\\\"Page\\\":\\\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\\\",\\\"Rating\\\":\\\"No Rating\\\",\\\"Image\\\":null,\\\"CurrentOpImage\\\":null,\\\"FileUploadDetails\\\":null,\\\"FirstOperatorName\\\":null,\\\"OperatorCount\\\":1,\\\"RequestTranscript\\\":false,\\\"Country\\\":null,\\\"OS\\\":null,\\\"Broswer\\\":null,\\\"Mobile\\\":null,\\\"iso_code\\\":null}]\""
```

**And I tried to get values out**

```
+ (void) showCurrentHistory:(NSString *) historyString {

    NSLog(@"Received String : %@", historyString);

    NSData *data = [historyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *e;
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];


    for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
        NSString *VisitorId         = [dic objectForKey:@"VisitorId"];
        NSString *VisitorSignalId   = [dic objectForKey:@"VisitorSignalId"];
        NSString *Type              = [dic objectForKey:@"Type"];
        NSString *Messagetext       = [dic objectForKey:@"Messagetext"];
        NSString *MessageTime       = [dic objectForKey:@"MessageTime"];
        NSString *Image             = [dic objectForKey:@"Image"];
        NSString *FileUploadDetails = [dic objectForKey:@"FileUploadDetails"];
        NSString *FirstOperatorName = [dic objectForKey:@"FirstOperatorName"];
        NSString *Rating            = [dic objectForKey:@"Rating"];


        NSLog(@"----------------------- Current  Chat History --------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"VisitorId           : %@" , VisitorId);
        NSLog(@"VisitorSignalId     : %@", VisitorSignalId);
        NSLog(@"Type                : %@" , Type);
        NSLog(@"Messagetext         : %@" , Messagetext);
        NSLog(@"MessageTime         : %@" , MessageTime);
        NSLog(@"Image               : %@", Image);
        NSLog(@"FileUploadDetails   : %@" , FileUploadDetails);
        NSLog(@"FirstOperatorName   : %@" , FirstOperatorName);
        NSLog(@"Rating              : %@" , Rating);
        NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

But its not entering the for loop. Can someone help me to fix this tnx.

Comment: What is `e` saying? And the JSON looks strange with all the escaped backslashes.

Comment: There is no error

Comment: What's wrong with the solution from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460099/get-values-from-nsdictionary ?

Comment: Can you show log of `NSLog(@"Response : %@", jsonArray);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` String may contains extra  `\\`  so you have to remove that one.

Please check below `JSON` string and code.

```
 NSString *str = @"[{\"VisitorId\":\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":\"06c6b36f-0d05-4f0c-bdee-1744c2cb6519\",\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"baman123 has joined the chat!\",\"IsJoin\":true,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-01-09 06:25:47\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"JoinMessage\",\"Name\":\"baman123\",\"Email\":\"baman123@gmail.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.122.233\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"hi this is baman\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-01-09 08:01:07\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"baman123\",\"Email\":\"baman123@gmail.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.122.233\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"are you there\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-01-09 08:01:10\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"baman123\",\"Email\":\"baman123@gmail.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.122.233\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"fuck u\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-01-09 08:01:14\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"baman123\",\"Email\":\"baman123@gmail.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.122.233\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":\"2270d224-2a82-4371-ae8e-43b98763eda6\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"sathyabaman\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-01-09 08:37:15\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"baman123\",\"Email\":\"baman123@gmail.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.122.233\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null}]";

 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[str UTF8String] length:str.length];
 NSError *error;

 NSMutableArray response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Hope this will helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting json string, you can convert json object from it like,

```
 id jsonString = yourJsonStringHere;

NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

   NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject);
```

Comment: Tnx. I tried but its giving (null)